# A more simpler way to construct a list of arguments?

Tags: c++, struct, mapper

I'm trying to create map[per] sort of code, but i'm looking for a more simpler way of coding a constructor.

An example:

```
#define B {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}


struct A {
    A(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0, int e = 0) {
        this->args[0] = a;
        this->args[1] = b;
        this->args[2] = c;
        this->args[3] = d;
        this->args[4] = e;
    };
    ~A() {};

    int args[5];

};
```

By more simpler I mean something like:

```
#define C { {},{},{},{} } 

struct B {
    B(){};
    int d,e;
    char f,g;
}

struct A {
    A(B b[] = {}) { };

    B strct[4];
}

A a = C;
```

Which I just can't get to work.

Comment: What do you mean by *more simpler*? The question is a bit vague.

Comment: I know, I mean less writing arguments to the list and more handled as an array or such. @super

Comment: In this example, you can leave your class as an aggregate and have no constructor at all. `A a{1,2,3,4,5};` works just fine without a constructor.

Answer (score 4):

If I'm understanding correctly, You're trying to find an easier way to construct class A:

```cpp
struct A
{
    A(int a = 0, int b = 0, int c = 0, int d = 0, int e = 0)
        : args{a, b, c, d, e} {};
    ~A(){};

    int args[5];
};
```

We can use braces to initialize array `int[5]`.

Comment: The template example shown is more of what i'm looking for, if you think about adding more arguments, it just becomes a huge manually written list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variadic template like...

```
struct A {
    template <typename... T>
    A(T... a) : args{a...} {};

    int args[5];
};

int main() {
    A a1(1);    // Initializes only the first element individually; others get default initialized (zero-initialized)
    A a2(1,2);  // first two elements get initialized individually
    // A a6(1,2,3,4,5,6);  // Error: Excess elements in array initializer
}
```

Comment: Is likely what i'm looking for, but how does it work for a struct, instead of ints?

Comment: The question is about ints, but the solution would work for other types, too. If you need something different, please show the code of what you actually want to achieve (even if pseudo-code).

Comment: Noted and added.

Comment: @Valtsuh: but `{}` (which has no type) cannot be used as argument of template so `A a{{}, {}}` won't work (it would with Shahriar's answer though, it is not template there). but `A a{B{}, B{}}` would for both answers.

Answer (score 1):

One option (C++11 and later) use an `initializer_list`.  For example;

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

struct A
{

    A(std::initializer_list<int> values) : args {0}
    {
        if (values.size() < 5)
            std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), args);
    }

    int args[5];
};

int main()
{
   A  a{1,2,3};    // note the values are in curly braces

   for (int v : a.args) std::cout << v << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The `args{0}` in the initialiser list of the constructor initialises all elements of `args` to zero, and the loop accepts up to five values in the initiliser list.   If there are more than five values supplied, all are ignored in the above.

If you want to use the arguments to create a container with an arbitrary number of `int`, you can do also use a standard container, such as `vector`.

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

struct A
{

    A(std::initializer_list<int> values) : args(values)
    {
    }

    std::vector<int> args;
};

// same main() as above.
```

In this case, the number of elements in `a.args` (i.e. `a.args.size()`) will be the same as that supplied (no trailing zeros, unless explicitly supplied).